# Javascript checkers game

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So I'm having trouble with this:

```
var checkerboard = [[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
                    [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
                    [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
                    [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
                    [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
                    [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
                    [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
                    [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]];
function setSquare(player, row, col) {
    // Your Code Here
}

function getPieceAt(row, col) {
    // Your Code Here
}
```

Here's the instruction:
setSquare, which places a player (either 'R' or 'B') at a particular row and column on the board.

getPieceAt, which returns the piece at a particular row and column; if there's no piece at that position, it should return null.

From what I understand, the first function should place 'R' and 'B' as you would place each piece. Second function I'm just out of the loop. Can anyone explain this simpler to me on what I should do?

Comment: So did your teacher show you how to access an array? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @epascarello yes. I just have a hard time understanding the way they explain it. So the way i understand it is I need to assign 'R' or 'B' to the right arrangements of a checkers board. How do you suggest I do this?

Comment: They pass in "R" or "B" (aka player) with the row and column position. So you set the string to the coordinates. Seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: Look at the link I provided, scroll to "Creating a two-dimensional array" Same basic idea...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the first function should only set one piece onto the board.

setSquare('R', 0, 0) should set the top left value in checkerboard to 'R'.  To set the contents of an array you type the array name, followed by the 'row', and 'col' numbers in brackets and set it to whatever player was passed to the function. (checkerboard[row][col] = player;)

getPieceAt is a lot like the first function, but instead of setting a value you look up the value and return that information.  To return information from a function you just type the word return, followed by the data you want to return.  This returns null if there is no piece at those coordinates. (return checkerboard[row][col];)

To actually set up the board, your program will need to call setSquare 24 times (assuming 12 'R' pieces and 12 'B' pieces).  Loops can come in handy here so you don't have to write out setSquare 24 times.

getPieceAt would be used while playing the game, to see if a piece was taken or to make sure the attempted move is onto an empty square.